Failed to apply plugin 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

Failed to apply plugin 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'.
The Crashlytics Gradle plugin 3 requires com.android.application version 8.1 or above. For more information, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-to-crashlytics-gradle-plugin-v3

Encountering this error while trying to build react native android app. How to fix it?

In my case, this issue was caused by a missing dependency in the root-level build.gradle file in the android  folder of my Flutter project. Here's what my buildscript block looks like after adding the correct dependencies:
buildscript {
    ext {
        appCompatVersion = "1.6.0"
        targetSdkVersion = 33
        compileSdkVersion = 34
        kotlin_version = "1.9.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.4'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.2'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}

Adding these dependencies resolved the missing plugin error. I know it's 3 weeks late, but I hope this helps!

hi, did find ant solution for this? I'm having the same error and don't know what to do

My solution is posted just above your comment -- I had a missing dependency in my root build.gradle file. Adding these lines in the buildscript.dependencies section resolved the build error.
FYI: I am building a Flutter project; I'm not using React Native. Although I was experiencing the exact same error message as OP, I'm not familiar with React Native and don't know how much of my solution is applicable.
